# jQuery - *:not() not excluding elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My goal is to disable right-click everywhere except `<kbd>` and `<textarea>` tags. I am using `*:not(kbd,textarea)` to exclude disabling right-click - `.on('contextmenu', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });`. It is supposed that I can right click on `<kbd>` and `<textarea>` tags but I cannot. It is werid.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('*:not(kbd,textarea)').on('contextmenu', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<kbd>right click me</kbd>
<textarea>right click me</textarea>
can't right click me
</div>
```

Comment: Does the `contextmenu` event bubble up my any chance so that it is prevented by the outer `<div>` (or `<body>`). edit: Yep, looks like that's it.

Comment: replace `$('*:not(kbd,textarea)')` to  `$('*:not(kbd):not(textarea))`

Comment: @IvanKaraman: And why would that be necessary?

Comment: @FelixKling, `contextmenu` shows when clicking outside of `<div>`. @IvanKaraman, I tried that before, that doesn't work.

Comment: @Felix Kling: If you're like me, and you absolutely despise using non-standard selectors even within jQuery, it can be seen as necessary even when it really isn't. (As for Ivan, I think he either doesn't realize that `:not(kbd,textarea)` works in jQuery, or, like many people, he worries too much about performance and prefers standard selectors for that reason.)

Comment: @BoltClock: yep, that makes sense. I assumed Ivan didn't know that that form works in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear: `*:not(kbd,textarea)` works just fine. The problem has to do with how events are processed in browsers.

Most events bubble up, [`contextmenu` does as well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu). Since the `<kbd>` and `<textarea>` elements are inside the `<div>`, the event handler bound to the `<div>` will always cancel the `contextmenu` event.

Depending on your exact use case, you could simply check whether the event originated on the element itself and only prevent it in that case:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('*:not(kbd,textarea)').on('contextmenu', function(e){
      if (this === e.target) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<kbd>right click me</kbd>
<textarea>right click me</textarea>
can't right click me
</div>
```

---

However, instead of binding the handler to every element, use event delegation. Bind the handler to the root of the document and check where the event originates from:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('contextmenu', function(e){
      if (!$(e.target).is('kbd,textarea')) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<kbd>right click me</kbd>
<textarea>right click me</textarea>
can't right click me
</div>
```

Comment: Typo. Should have used `e` instead of `event`. Thanks!

Comment: Uh, I see what's wrong now because I was curious why `div > *:not(kbd,textarea)` doesn't work either.